# C# Load XML values to dictionary with name as index

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I have this XML for example

```
<DEV>
   <families>
       <Family Name = "King">
         <Child Num = "1">
            <ChildName> John </ChildName>
            <Details>
                <Height> 1.80 </Height>
                <Weight> 78 </Weight>
                <Age> 16 </Age>
            </Details>
         </Child>
         <Child Num = "2">
            <ChildName> Jim </ChildName>
            <Details>
                <Height> 1.90 </Height>
                <Weight> 88</Weight>
                <Age> 18</Age>
            </Details>
         </Child>
       </Family>
       <Family Name = "Trud">
         <Child Num = "1">
            <ChildName> Bill </ChildName>
            <Details>
                <Height> 1.50 </Height>
                <Weight> 78 </Weight>
                <Age> 27 </Age>
            </Details>
         </Child>
         <Child Num = "2">
            <ChildName> Alise </ChildName>
            <Details>
                <Height> 1.40 </Height>
                <Weight> 56</Weight>
                <Age> 12</Age>
            </Details>
         </Child>
       </Family>
    </Families>
</DEV>
```

Is there any way to have a dictionary with all of the Height values so then i could search by the child name? for example Weight_arr["Bill"] will give me 78.

All names are unique... Means no chance there will be 2 Bill...

For now i know i can get an array of weights like this... but i can't search by names, just by indexes.

```
    string[] arr = XDocument.Load(path + @"\Pages\Fams.xml").Descendants("Weight")
                .Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, double> weigths = document
   .Descendants("Child")
   .ToDictionary(
       e => e.Element("ChildName").Value,
       e => (double) e.Element("Details").Element("Weight")  );
```